How do we calculate the gower distance between one record in one dataset and all records in second dataset in R?
I want to calculate the gower distance between a record of dataset 1 and all records of dataset 2. The first approach is written as below
library(gower)

data(iris)
dat1 <- iris[1:10,]
dat2 <- iris[11:30,]

# first approach
gower::gower_dist(dat1[1,], dat2)

This gives me the results with length of 20.
0.09079365 0.09873016 0.16142857 0.29476190 0.20920635 0.33079365 
0.21936508 0.05000000 0.23952381 0.11507937 0.12095238 0.15079365 
0.16984127 0.24523810 0.16539683 0.12920635 0.17206349 0.03555556 
0.02761905 0.14063492

Can I interpret the first value as the gower distance between dat1[1,] and dat2[1,] and the second value as the gower distance between dat1[1,] and dat2[2,] and so on?
What confused me is that the results are different if I calculate
gower::gower_dist(dat1[1,],dat2[1,])

which gives me
0.75

This is different from 0.09079365. Ultimately, I want to calculate the gower distance of each observation in dat1 with every observation in dat2. If I use the second approach, I will need to add a for loop over all the observations in dat2 as follows.
# second approach
for(i in 1:nrow(dat2)) {
  print(gower::gower_dist(dat1[1,],dat2[i,]))
}

Since these two approaches give different results, which one should I use to achieve the purpose?

Please don't post duplicates of questions you have already asked.

I have additional questions on this, and already deleted the previous post.

The simple solution is to use the StatMatch implementation.

If I used gower.dist from StatMatch, can I write gower::gower_dist(dat1[1,],dat2) to find the distance between the first obs in dat1 and all obs in dat2? @whuber

That's how I read the documentation.  Be aware that the Gower distance depends on all the data, which is why you got different answers.  If you're not clear about that, you are at risk of misinterpreting the results.

So, what code should I write to achieve the purpose of this post? That is the thing I am confused about. Since I need to find the minimum distance between one record in data1 and all records in data2, I need to get the distance vector in which each element is a distance between that record in data1 and one record in data2.

My understanding is the following.  gower distance of continuous variables depend on the range of values of  that variable. So in the
gower::gower_dist(dat1[1,], dat2)
case it computes the ranges using both dat1p[1,] and all of dat2. But in the
gower::gower_dist(dat1[1,],dat2[1,])
case the range for some  of the variables is different. In fact when running the example I get a warning message of "skipping variable with zero or non-finite range". That explains the difference in values of the first and second calls.
So the correct way is the first call
gower::gower_dist(dat1[1,], dat2)

Thank you! That is what I thought as well. Thank you for your answer!
